# OpenCV - Creating an Ellipse shaped mask in python

Tags: python, opencv, ellipse

I've extracted a Circle shaped mask from an image in OpenCV. I used the following code for the same:

```
H, W = img.shape
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(W), np.arange(H))**
d2 = (x - xc)**2 + (y - yc)**2**
mask = d2 < r **2**
```

And, used the mask value to find the average color outside the circle.

```
outside = np.ma.masked_where(mask, img)**
average_color = outside.mean()**
```

I want to extract an Ellipse from an image in the same above process in OpenCV Python.

Thank You.

Comment: Does cv::ellipse drawing function works also in python? If yes, just use it

Comment: cv:ellipse drawing function works in python, but it just draws the ellipse,  does not masks it.

Comment: Draw a filled ellipse :D

Comment: Will that work ? 
Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: Yes, same for cv::circle

Comment: Can you provide a piece of code for that?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 3):

**Drawing Ellipse**

To draw the ellipse, we need to pass several arguments. One argument is the center location (x,y). Next argument is axes lengths (major axis length, minor axis length). angle is the angle of rotation of ellipse in anti-clockwise direction. startAngle and endAngle denotes the starting and ending of ellipse arc measured in clockwise direction from major axis. i.e. giving values 0 and 360 gives the full ellipse. For more details, check the documentation of cv2.ellipse(). Below example draws a half ellipse at the center of the image.

```
cv2.ellipse(img,(256,256),(100,50),0,0,180,255,-1)
```

*Taken from Miki's Link in the Question Comments*

Comment: Just a heads up, the angle of rotation is now clockwise, not sure when/if it switched.